# Generic parameter 'Parameters' could not be inferred in swift? Alamofire with generics

Tags: swift, xcode, oop, generics, alamofire

I have an issue about Alamofire and generic use:

```
struct Network{
static func getApiRequest<T>(model:BaseNetworkClass,type : T.Type,completionHandler:@escaping (T)->(),errorHandler:@escaping (String) ->()) where T:Decodable{
    AF.request(model.request(), method: model.httpMethod as! HTTPMethod, parameters: nil, encoder:URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default , headers: nil, interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil).responseDecodable { (response:AFDataResponse<T>) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let res):
            completionHandler(res)
            break
        case .failure(let err):
            errorHandler(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
        
}
}
`
```

When I try to use it I get the error `"Generic parameter 'Parameters' could not be inferred"`:  [image: errorMessage]

What is my mistake?

Comment: show us how you try to use it, since this is where the error is.

Comment: @workingdog ı cant even use it because it is give me error which ı mentioned

Comment: show us how you call this `getApiRequest`, as you said, this is where you get the error.

Comment: @workingdog ı have just added ımage of error you can look up . ı dont use this method in anywhere because it gives me this errorMessage.I could not explain myself clearly sorry about that point

Comment: @Sait47 don't use two completion handlers. You should use Swift generic enum `Result` with `.success` and `.failure`. Btw you need to explicitly set the resulting type.

Comment: That particular Alamofire `request` method requires generic parameters. If you don't provide a type, it can't infer one. In that case it's better to just leave out the `parameters` and `encoder` parameters altogether and have a separate method to use when you actually send parameters. (This question should be reopened so I can answer. It has nothing to do with completion handlers.)

Comment: You can also use `request.responseData` instead of `responseJSON` or `responseDecodable `

Answer (score 0):

I don't have AF, however could you try something like this, and tell us what you get:

```
struct Network {
    
    static func getApiRequest<T: Decodable>(model: BaseNetworkClass, completionHandler: @escaping (T)->(), errorHandler: @escaping (String) ->()) {
        AF.request(model.request(), method: model.httpMethod as! HTTPMethod, parameters: nil, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default , headers: nil, interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil).responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let res):
                completionHandler(res)
                break
            case .failure(let err):
                errorHandler(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get the same error unfortunately @workingdog

Comment: One can use `request.responseData`